# Is it possible to rename multiple list names in a list?

Tags: r, list, apply

I want to rename my list names in a list.

For example:

```
library(randNames) #using this package for the random names for the example
my_info <- rand_names(10)
my_second_info <- rand_names(10)

list1 <- list(A = c(my_info$name.first), B = c(rnorm(1:10)), C = c(rnorm(1:10)), D = c(rnorm(1:10)))
list2 <- list(A = c(my_second_info$name.first), B = c(rnorm(1:10)), C = c(rnorm(1:10)), D = c(rnorm(1:10)))

both_lists <- list(list1,list2)
```

And now when I call both_lists I get [[1]] as a name for the first list and [[2]] as a name of the second list ([as depicted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWVD2.png)).

I would like to change the name of list1 and list2 (and for all others that may be added to it), to the first name random name. So list 1 would be named the both_lists[[1]]$A[1] and list 2 would be named to both_lists[[2]]$A[1].

Is this possible? Or does the list name get lost for example when making a list of lists and it just becomes a specific number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to extract 1st value from `A` sublist in all the lists and assign it as name.

```
names(both_lists) <- sapply(both_lists, function(x) x$A[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `names()`

`names(both_lists) <- c(both_lists[[1]]$A[1],both_lists[[2]]$A[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You may use `setNames` by the values you get in the first row when you use `unlist` in an `sapply`.

```
both_lists <- setNames(both_lists, sapply(both_lists, unlist)[1,])

names(both_lists)
# [1] "Vilma" "Naomi"
```

---

*Data:* I used your code with `set.seed(42)`.